# oracle express detatach

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-xe, detach

Hi I am new and I am used to MS SQL Manager's Attach/Detatch functionality to drop a database into a single file so I can move it to other computers/SQL instances. In a nut shell, this is what I want to do.

I have a large Oracle Express database (instance name Zeus) that I need to move onto other Oracle Express instances (brand new installs) and then later I need to keep them updated with Zeus' database.

How do I do this?
I am not understanding how to export the database/schema - user definition/permission, table definitions, and table data.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can easily do that with Oracle (especially XE edition).

You would usually do an [Import](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#i1007653)/[Export](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm). This would give something like :

`expdp system/password@XE DUMPFILE=expfull.dmp FULL=y

impdp system/password@XE DUMPFILE=expfull.dmp FULL=y`

The expfull.dmp files would be located in a folder named oradata/dpdump in the Oracle XE
installation.

You could also use [Transportable Tablespaces](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tspaces.htm#ADMIN01101) as [described here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/transport.htm#sthref729) and [summarized here](http://www.psoug.org/reference/tts.html).

[Another method](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_db_copy.htm) involves 10 steps and would have to be adapted to Oracle XE. I mention it here for reference.